# Inverting a Set of Equations Consistently

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Let $n$ be an integer. Let $x = n/c$, where $c$ is a predetermined constant and let the remainder, $r$, be $r = n - (x \times c)$. We defined two additional integers as follows:

> $$ \text{If} \;  r = 0, \text{then} \; k = x \; \text{and} \; l =c;   $$
>
> $$ \text{If} \;  r \neq 0, \text{then} \; k = x + 1 \; \text{and} \; l = r.   $$

I need help with inverting the set of equations. Assume that $k$ and $l$ are given. How does one determine $n$, consistent with the rule above on a case by case basis -- as above. It'd be great for both the cases, someone could give me easily programmable conditions -- ideally in terms of the inputs, $k$ and $l$.

Answer (score 2):

If $l=c$, then you're in the first case, and
$$n=cx+r=ck$$
If $l<c$, then you're in the second case, and
$$n=cx+r=cx+l=c(k-1)+l$$